# Add a cookie to response in Request Listener

Tags: php, symfony, cookies

I have a Listener in my Symfony2 application, which listens Request events, to update last connection date of my users.

It works fine, but I would like to add (or refresh) a cookie on the same event. I found some ressources, which said to access to the Response through $event->getResponse(), but this value is `NULL` in my case.

I've seen that it is possible to create a new Response *via* `setReponse`, but I don't want to set the whole response, I just want to add a cookie.

Is there a way to do that ?

Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listen to `kernel.response` event. So you will have access to `Response` object which selected controller returns. Read more about that on [After Filters with the kernel.response Event](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/event_dispatcher/before_after_filters.html#after-filters-with-the-kernel-response-event) documentation page.

Also, take a look at [The HttpKernel Component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_kernel/introduction.html) for information about events and general request pipeline.

Comment: Ok, you're right I should listen the ```kernel.response```. But in the doc, I don't see the difference between filter on a reponse and a listener on response, can you give me a clue ?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by filter? You only register your listener functions for events to implement some logic that needs to be done on every user request. You can call this logic as `filters`, so you filterting the user request to match some condition.

Comment: I don't understand the difference, in the docs, between a ```FilterResponseEvent``` and a ```GetResponseEvent```. It seems to do the same thing.